# What is the word order in the founding documents of American history?

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis, old-english

Apparently, the historical document passages in SAT tests have some sort of twisted word order. I wonder if there is a proper text on the grammatical word order rules for such documents. 
P.S. I searched online for "the english grammar in founding documents" and other similar links, but nothing useful has come up.

Comment: The title and body of your question are not the same, could you [edit] to clarifywhat you're asking?

Comment: Old English was replaced by Middle English around 1100 AD, about 400-500 years before English speakers came to America.

Comment: Do you have a specific passage example?

Comment: They’re late 18th century and don’t seem to be very different from today. Quote the text that puzzles you.

Comment: There is no set pattern if you are talking about many documents, other than sounding formal or old-fashioned. SAT tests include one example at a time, not founding documents as a library.